# How do I create a manual reset event that only allows access to particular user accounts in C++?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, events, event-handling

I am fairly new to C++...I have the CreateEvent working okay with this code:

```
HANDLE result = CreateEvent(NULL,                     // No security.
                            TRUE,                     // Manual-reset event.
                            FALSE,                    // Not signaled.
                            L"Global\\MyResetEvent"); // Event name.
```

But what do I have to do with the security attributes to have an equivalent of the following in C#?

```
SecurityIdentifier localSystemUsers = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.LocalSystemSid, null);
SecurityIdentifier adminUsers = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid, null);
EventWaitHandleAccessRule localSystemRule = new EventWaitHandleAccessRule(localSystemUsers, EventWaitHandleRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
EventWaitHandleAccessRule adminRule = new EventWaitHandleAccessRule(adminUsers, EventWaitHandleRights.Synchronize | EventWaitHandleRights.Modify, AccessControlType.Allow);
EventWaitHandleSecurity security = new EventWaitHandleSecurity();
security.AddAccessRule(localSystemRule);
security.AddAccessRule(adminRule);
bool createdNew;
event = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, MyEventName, out createdNew, security);
```

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to get a C# tag on this question.

Comment: @FredLarson Done. Let's see what happens :P Thanks.

Comment: I've never done it, but this link looks helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446595%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @MadScienceDreams I am trying to follow along and do it this way but it keeps returning false on creating the event!

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to add one step. Great find, thanks!

Comment: You'll need to secure the object. You passed `NULL` as `lpEventAttributes`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Dave, that's not what I was missing, haha...my question revolves solely around was what that security detail should be... :P

Comment: I've always found `ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor` to be the simplest way to create a security descriptor. For an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms717798(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I'm still not exactly sure how I would use AllocateAndInitializeSid to allow local system account services to interact with this...what would the correct SIDs be to pass in as the parameters?

Comment: You're doing it the hard way. With `ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor` and some SDDL it's a one-liner.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yeah, I'm looking at that now...but how do I know what TEXT entries to use? I need Local System and Administrators to get access. TEXT("(A;OICI;GA;;;BA)"); is Administrators, but Local System?

Comment: Don't think you need `OICI` for an event. `GA` is `GENERIC_ALL`, is that what you want? Local system is `S-1-5-18`. Not sure about `EventWaitHandleRights.Synchronize | EventWaitHandleRights.Modify`. May need to resort to hex for them.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How do you get all of this information to assemble the TEXT entry?

Comment: You read the documentation. Follow the various links out of the topic that I linked to. Use websearch.

Comment: Dave, you seem to be way better than me at searching through this content and far more experienced with eventing. Why not post a working solution and I will accept it as an answer, if anything, for points at least?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it, in the end, thanks to [this link](http://www.netid.washington.edu/documentation/domains/sddl.aspx):

```
    TCHAR *szSD = TEXT("D:")        // Discretionary ACL.
        TEXT("(A;OICI;GA;;;BA)");   // Allow full control to administrators.
        TEXT("(A;OICI;GA;;;SY)");   // Allow full control to the local system.
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;
    ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(szSD, SDDL_REVISION_1, &((&sa)->lpSecurityDescriptor), NULL);
    HANDLE result = CreateEvent(&sa, TRUE, FALSE, L"Global\\CustomManualResetEvent");
```